# Function pointer to address (c++)

Tags: function, pointers

```
    int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int c;
        int (*p)(int,int);
        p = &Add;
        c = p(2,3);
        printf("%d", c);
    }
```

As you can see above, I'm using Add in the function pointer. I want to be able to use an address in the place of "&Add" e.g.

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    int (*p)(int,int);
    p = 0x123456;
    c = p(2,3);
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in the same way as how you declared the function pointer by casting the address.

```
int (*p)(int,int);
p = ( int(*)(int,int) ) 0x123456;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to cast the constant to the function pointer type. Like so

```
typedef int(*func_t)(int,int);
int main()
{
    int c;
    func_t p;
    p = (func_t)0x123456;
    c = p(2,3);
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

I encourage you to typedef your function types as I have done because it makes it much easier to understand.

And as always, I hope you know what you're doing and know that that address refers to the address of a function with that signature, otherwise you invoke undefined behavior.